# npm run build error in nextJS and vercel deploy

Tags: deployment, build, next.js, vercel

I have an app already deploy on vercel , i change just a a content in a page and push it on git without problem(i make that many times without problem before), but now i can't execute npm run build return an error , the same error on vercel deploy.
Can any one help me to fix this issue.

00:50:06.011    > next .next/build
00:50:06.209    > No such directory exists as the project root: /vercel/workpath0/portfolio/.next/build

the script in package.json

```
"scripts": {
"dev": "next dev",
"build": "next .next/build",
"start": "next start"
```

},

[vercel deploy terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ik8Sc.png)

Comment: `build` script should be `"build": "next build"`

Comment: yes it work thanks, but i dont understnd why , the other project i have work fine whith the same script.

Comment: anyway thanks  @NileshPatel :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason its failing with "No such directory exists" is because the `.next` directory doesn't exist until you run [next build](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cli#build), which is the command that generates the output.

Change your build script to `next build`, like it shows in the [Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started#manual-setup), and it will work.